# Trying to sort a ListView with unchecked items at the top and then by ID: compare routine throws an odd exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm building a desktop to-do list app, and in my UI I have a `ListView` control which lists all the items in each list. Each item/row has a checkbox which updates the status of that item in the database when it is checked or unchecked. So far so good!

What I am attempting to do is re-sort the list whenever a checkbox is clicked, so that the list is always sorted with the unchecked items at the top, and then by ID (which is an `int` value stored in the `Tag` property of each `ListViewItem` when the list is loaded).

I've written a custom comparer implementing `IComparer` and call `Sort()` on the `ListView` in the `ItemChecked` event handler:

```
/// <summary>
/// Complete or uncomplete a todo item when it's checked/unchecked
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void _taskList_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    var list = sender as ListView;
    var itemId = e.Item.Tag.ToString();

    if(e.Item.Tag != null)
    {
        if(e.Item.Checked)
            // Do some database stuff here to mark as complete
        else
            // Do some database stuff here to mark as not completed
    }

    // Resort the listview
    list.ListViewItemSorter = new TaskListComparer();
    list.Sort();
}
```

Here is my comparer:

```
public class TaskListComparer : IComparer
{
    public TaskListComparer()
    {
    }

    public int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        // Convert the two passed values to ListViewItems
        var item1 = a as ListViewItem;
        var item2 = b as ListViewItem;

        // Get the unique ID's of the list items (stored in the Tag property)
        var item1Id = Convert.ToInt32(item1.Tag);
        var item2Id = Convert.ToInt32(item2.Tag);

        // First sort on the Checked property (unchecked items should be at the top)
        if (item1.Checked && !item2.Checked)
            return 1;
        else if (!item1.Checked && item2.Checked)
            return -1;

        // If both items were checked or both items were unchecked, 
        // sort by the ID (in descending order)
        if (item1Id > item2Id)
            return 1;
        else if (item1Id < item2Id)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

However, when I check an item, the following exception is thrown when the sort is attempted:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
    Message="InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.\r\nParameter name: index"
    Source="System.Windows.Forms"
    ParamName="index"
```

And in the debugger, if I inspect the `item1.Checked` property in the compare routine I see:

```
'item1.Checked' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
```

The other item's `Checked` property shows up fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.index.aspx) of your `ListViewItem` is `-1` (the [Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.checked.aspx) property uses `Index` internally). That's normally the case only before the `ListViewItem` is added to the `ListView`.

In your case, the item might have been temporarily removed from the list during sorting. In other words, it does not look safe to access the `Checked` property from a sort routine.

Comment: Yes, he should save something like a `Dictionary<ListViewItemId,CheckStatus>` in the `ItemChecked` handler, pass it to the comparer and then use it to get the checked information instead of using the `Checked` property.

Comment: Thanks guys, this answer and comment were both helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Try to return `0` instead if `-1` because it seems that the value returned by `Compare()` becomes an index of the item.